# Representations of SO(3) and vector bundles on BSO(3)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

Let $V$ be the vector bundle over $BSO(3)$ associated to the adjoint representation of $SO(3).$  Then $V$ does not have a nonzero section.  One way to see this is that the Steifel-Whitney class $w_3(V)$ is nonzero.

Question: What about $V \oplus V$ or $V \oplus V \oplus \dots \oplus V?$

1. Do these bundles have a nonzero section?
2. If not, is there a characteristic class of some sort which obstructs the existence of such a section?

Comments:

1. The representation given by the direct sum of $n$ copies of the adjoint does not have a one dimensional invariant subspace.  Is that the same as (1) above??
2. The complexification $V \otimes {\mathbb C}$ has trivial third Chern class.

Thanks.  Jonathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$w_{3n}(nV)=w_3(V)^n\neq 0$. The (mod $2$) Euler class takes direct sums to cup products.